# Consulta SQL - Artículo y valor en vigencia

Tags: mysql

¿Cómo se realizaría la consulta que devuelva el siguiente resultado?

Obtener todos los artículos (`id`s), la fecha de compra y el valor en vigencia al momento de la compra.

Para eso dispongo de 2 tablas

Tabla Articulos

```
id-tabla, id_articulo, fecha_compra
1          1           2016-05-05
2          2           2017-05-05
3          1           2018-05-05
```

Tabla Vigencia

```
id_tabla, id_articulo, fecha_desde, valor
1         1            2014-01-01   10
2         2            2016-01-01   15
3         1            2018-01-01   22
```

no logro dar pié con bola...

Debería devolver

```
id_articulo, fecha_compra, precio_vigente
1            2016-05-05    10
2            2017-05-05    15
1            2018-05-05    22
```

Comment: ¿En qué versión de mySQL trabajas?

Comment: Estoty trabajando con mariadb-10.2.18 en Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo esencial es determinar cual de las fechas de vigencias le corresponde a cada fila de `Articulos`, y según te entiendo, sería la fecha anterior más cercana a la de compra. Esto traducido en código sería:

```
SELECT      T1.id_articulo,
            T1.fecha_compra,
            MAX(T2.fecha_desde) as 'fecha_desde'
            FROM Articulos T1
            LEFT JOIN Vigencia T2
                ON T2.id_articulo = T1.id_articulo
                AND T2.fecha_desde <= T1.fecha_compra 
            GROUP BY T1.id_articulo, T1.fecha_compra
```

Luego simplemente habría que utilizar esto en una subconsulta para llegar al `valor`:

```
SELECT  A.id_articulo,
        A.fecha_compra,
        V.valor
    FROM (SELECT    T1.id_articulo,
            T1.fecha_compra,
            MAX(T2.fecha_desde) as 'fecha_desde'
            FROM Articulos T1
            LEFT JOIN Vigencia T2
                ON T2.id_articulo = T1.id_articulo
                AND T2.fecha_desde <= T1.fecha_compra 
            GROUP BY T1.id_articulo, T1.fecha_compra
    ) A
    INNER JOIN Vigencia V
        ON A.id_articulo = V.id_articulo
        AND V.fecha_desde = A.fecha_desde
```

Comment: Capo di tutti i capi, el que sabe sabe... eso es lo que busco :D

Answer (score 0):

si lo que requieres es obtener el campo valor de tu tabla vigencia, apartir de tu tabla articulos puedes intentar acceder a tus datos mediante un join

algo asi

```
select a.id-articulo,a.fecha-compra, v.valor as precio-vigente 
from articulos a
inner join vigencia v on v.id-articulo = a.id-articulo
```

puedes emplear alias para referirte a tus tablas

Comment: Andrex, eso me devuelve las combinaciones..... lo mismo que la respuesta anterior

Comment: edite la respuesta de modo que arroje el resultado de tu edición

Comment: Me sigue dando la combinación de filas andrex ... probado con mariaDb 10.2.18 (con la que estoy trabajando) y lo probé con mysql 5.6 por las dudas que sea eso

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TBL_ARTICULOS.id_articulo, 
TBL_ARTICULOS.fecha_compra,
TBL_VIGENCIA.valor,
TBL_VIGENCIA.fecha_desde 
FROM TBL_ARTICULOS 
INNER JOIN TBL_VIGENCIA ON TBL_ARTICULOS.Id_articulo=TBL_VIGENCIA.Id_articulo
```

Comment: Nop fredi, lo que ando buscando es que me devuelva <br> 1 - 2016-05-05 - 10 <br> 2 - 2017-05-05 - 15 <br> 1 - 2018-05-05 - 22

Comment: Responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Hice la consulta talcual como lo pides, lo unico seria quitarle a la consulta TBL_VIGENCIA.fecha_desde